# Screenshot of Android Emulator from Android Studio 0.9.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I take a screenshot of any AVD with Android Studio or Android Device Monitor, I get a black screen. Has anyone else encountered this? What do I do to fix it? Is this a bug with the Android tools?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me the method of how you took that screenshot ?

Comment: @Outofmemory I clicked the Camera icon in the Android view in Android Studio. I get similar results in Android Device Monitor and using `adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png`.

Comment: Possibly related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60359

Comment: I wonder why would you want to take a screenshot that way. Please use a third party screen capture software.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice -- That bug is correct. Try turning off GPU acceleration.

Comment: @Outofmemory can you name a third party package which I can easily install on the emulator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a bug on emulator of Android. Please turn off **Host GPU** on your emulator settings.

Step:

1. Open Android Virtual Device Manager.
2. Click **Edit** icon of your emulator.
3. On **Emulated performance**, uncheck **Use Host GPU**
4. Click **Finish** and start your emulator again.

Everything will be normal.

Answer (score 1):

try to get screenshot if you use Windows 8

**WIN key + Prt Sc** Button

Comment: 1. I'm not on Windows. 2. This will give all the window decorations and not just the device's screen. (Removing the window decorations is a PITA.) 3. This doesn't address the issue of whether or not there is a bug in the Android tools.

Comment: `2. This will give all the window decorations and not just the device's screen.`, You could crop the emulator screen easily in a photo editor.

Comment: @Outofmemory using a photo editor takes a significant amount of manual labor and time

Answer (score 1):

Press **Prt Sc** button and Open **Paint** and Paste

Comment: Yes, I know how to manually take a screen shot. But then I will have to manually remove all of the window decorations to get just the device screen. My question is whether or not this is a bug in Android Studio, adb, the emulator, or some other Android development tool. (p.s. It's not safe to assume that everyone develops on Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this tool "ligth shot", it allows you to crop, edit, copy and save using direct own browser, operating system.

see link: http://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html